# Run `stripe webhook_endpoints create` command from Revin in `Dockerfile.studio`?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, stripe-payments

Currently, I am using [`stripe listen`](https://stripe.com/docs/cli/listen) command which is in `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
  # Stripe Webhook CLI
  stripe:
    image: stripe/stripe-cli:latest
    command: listen --forward-to host.docker.internal:3000/api/stripe/webhooks --log-level warn
    extra_hosts:
      - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
    environment:
      STRIPE_API_KEY: ${STRIPE_SECRET_TEST_API_KEY}
    # Make sure log colors show up correctly
    tty: true
```

It outputs:

> Ready! Your webhook signing secret is whsec_abcdefg1234567

But, [Revin](https://getrevin.com) doesn't provide access to `stripe-cli` directly (see [faq](https://digitalentities.notion.site/Documentation-229455f8658e4784a981268d636dd9f2?p=ccdc6988542c47ca8ef15c4a862b531c&pm=c)) so I have to use another command to get the webhook signing secret.

Currently, I trigger it manually by stopping my server & then running the command:

```bash
stripe webhook_endpoints create --url="https://15d4-2405-201-b-10c8-a85e-337-357-7556.ngrok.io/api/stripe/webhooks" -d "enabled_events[]"="charge.succeeded"
```

This command returns the webhook signing secret in JSON format.

How do I run this command inside `Dockerfile.studio` or `docker-compose.yml`?

I did try adding 2 lines (above `prisma`) to my `Dockerfile.studio`:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/studio

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5555

RUN docker run --rm -it stripe/stripe-cli:latest
RUN stripe webhook_endpoints create --url="http://localhost:3000/api/stripe/webhooks" -d "enabled_events[]"="charge.succeeded"

RUN npm install -g prisma
CMD npx prisma studio
```

But it doesn't work & the command fails when I do `docker-compose up`.

Is there any solution to this? Do I need to use `ngrok` in place of `localhost` or is it possible to just use `localhost` with `stripe`?

Answer (score 0):

Your docker-compose should contain two services: one is your webhook api and the other is the stripe-cli forwarding to the first one

```
version: '3.8'

services:
 webhook-api:
   image: webhook-api
   build:
     context: .
   container_name: webhook-api
   ports:
     - "127.0.0.1:5555:5555"
 stripe-cli:
   image: stripe/stripe-cli
   container_name: stripe-cli
   command: "listen --forward-to webhook-api:5555/api/stripe/webhooks"
   environment:
     - STRIPE_API_KEY=rk_test_…
```

Don’t forget to fill the env var **STRIPE_API_KEY** with your restricted secret key https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-cli/keys

Comment: no, this does not work. i got `failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount920660637/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
ERROR: Service 'webhook-api' failed to build : Build failed` & this also doesn't get the webhook signing secret bcz you have never specified the usage of `stripe webhook_endpoints create` command.

Comment: You need to update the docker-compose.yml so that it uses your nodejs application build.context
You'll have the secret once the application is up, you should see in your logs something like:
Ready! You are using Stripe API Version [2020-08-27]. Your webhook signing secret is whsec_....

Comment: i see the webhook secret when using with stripe. the `stripe webhook_endpoints create` command is from revin. check out the mentioned links above. the original code works for showing me what you say but i want it to automate it when using revin. i think you are misunderstanding my question. please re-read again.

Comment: Thanks for your patience! just trying to help :)
So the `webhook_endpoints create` registers a hosted api as an endpoint, you can't use a local running instance (in your case a running docker service)
Btw, when using `stripe webhook_endpoints create` you are using stripe-cli here
Otherwise in the documentation, it doesn't mention that you couldn't use `stripe listen  --forward-to` with Revin, could you please share a link ? it mention that you couldn't use login or the api-key, that's why I suggested to use an env var in the docker-compose

Comment: yeah, it's the stripe-cli not revin's. see the links in the original post. that's all the links you should be looking at. all i want to do is automate the process of `stripe webhook_endpoints create` & get the webhook signing secret when i launch `docker-compose up`